# How to access a custom field of a list using REST

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, rest

I'm trying to get information from a list in a custom SPField called "My Field" with the internal name "MyField" using this JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://<URL>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=MyField",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
            console.log(value.MyField);
        });
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.warn(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

MyField has a custom field value type.

I found this description

> Not all types of column are available via REST, most annoyingly managed metadata columns are amongst this group of unsupported column types. Further, not all types of column will return data for an entry just by including them in the $select parameter, an example of which is Lookup (single or multi-value) columns.
>   [...](http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/)

Is this still the case, and what do I have to implement in the custom SPField, to make it retrievable via REST ...

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the select (i.e. bring back all the field values) and see if the value of MyField is included in the response.

Comment: @RobWindsor: Thanks, I've just tested it, but unfortunately it is returning `undefined` for all items and there is also no `MyField` member if I expand the `value`-objects ... also adding `?$select=*` is not solving the issue...

Comment: do you mean you defined a custom field type like outlined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862248%28v=office.14%29.aspx if that's the case I would be surprised if the REST API would be able to return data from your field because it could possibly use some data structure that the REST API isn't designed to handle -- why did you decide to go with a custom field type if that's the case (for my own curiosity)?

Comment: @John-M: Yes exactly as described in your referenced article, except that I'm on SP2013. The application design was not in my hands, but is comprehensible since it is a rather complex representation of metadata with inheritance, an own rendering pattern and some other features, that SP cannot represent with OOB terms.
As already hinted in my initial question, I somehow thought that it would be rather difficult for SP to decide what to emit from this field - however I was hoping for a way to control this, e.g. by implementing a specific interface or by overriding a method ....

Comment: You'll probably have to extend and deploy your own REST endpoint with your own functionality to accomplish this

Comment: For everyone that stumbles upon this question, [this link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Extending-SharePoint-2013-c39d01ae) might help.
We postponed this issue in our product, but will eventually come back - I will update this question as soon as I've verified the solution.

Comment: It may be possible to create a Calculated Column, then set its formula to be "[MyField]". The Calculated Column should be available via REST.

Comment: @OmarStewey: Very good idea, thank you I will test that tomorrow!

Comment: http://<URL>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=MyField Paste your URL in chrome browser and see what exception it is giving. Also what type of column it is ?.

Answer (score 1):

If my field is **Taxonomy Column**, I would take a look at this [blog](http://sharepointificate.blogspot.no/2014/05/taxonomy-columns-sharepoint-2013-list.html).

It explains how to retrive **Taxonomy columns** with **REST**.

Basically you need to do a Post to a different endpoint:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://sharepointificate/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'<View><Query></Query></View>'}",
    type: "POST",
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code gives the results of the field into a variable called myfield.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',update);
var returnedItems;
function update(){

var context=new SP.ClientContext();
var list=context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');

var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query></Query></View>");
returnedItems=list.getItems(caml);
context.load(returnedItems);
context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback,onFailedCallback);

}

function onSucceededCallback(sender,args){
alert();
var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator(); 

while(enumerator.moveNext()){
var listItem=enumerator.get_current();
var myfield=listItem.get_item('MyField');

}
    }

function onFailedCallback(sender,args){
alert("Failed to connect:  "+args.get_message());
}
</script>
```

You can access the variable in javascript and use it anywhere from JS

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
dataType: "json",
```

after

```
type: "GET",
```

Comment: Hi Charles, I've finally tested it and is behaving exactly the same (as expected somehow ...)